# Problem in importing statsmodels.api in jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, statsmodels

I am trying to import statsmodel.api for conducting a linear regression in jupyter notebook (python 3 kernel). But I am getting the following error:

https://gist.github.com/ashusopku/e7e4da92babfdab5952f6836f2d4af69

Please help as I cannot find any solution to the problem elsewhere.

Comment: This fails with importing scipy. You might more likely get an answer asking for the specific problem with scipy or anaconda.

Comment: Re-installing the Jupyter notebook did the trick for me